# CassandraSQLContext key not found

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark-sql

Can someone help me with this error

Here my table in cassandra

```
CREATE TABLE zz("timestamp" timestamp, "sessionId" text, "userId" text, PRIMARY KEY ("userId", "sessionId", "timestamp"));
```

with some data

```
INSERT INTO rr ("userId", "sessionId", "timestamp") VALUES ('1', '1', 1);
```

I use Spark with Java to query my data with SQL

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf(true).setMaster("local").setAppName("DatastaxTests").set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost");
SparkContext ctx = new SparkContext(conf);
SparkContextJavaFunctions functions = CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(ctx);

CassandraSQLContext cassandraContext = new CassandraSQLContext(ctx);
cassandraContext.setKeyspace("crm360retail");

DataFrame userIdRDD = cassandraContext.sql("SELECT * FROM rr");
System.out.println("Data fetched: \n" + StringUtils.join(userIdRDD.collect(), "\n"));
```

But when I execute the code I have this error

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: userId
at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:58)
at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:58)
at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraTableScan$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CassandraTableScan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraTableScan$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(CassandraTableScan.scala:29)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraTableScan$$anonfun$1.apply(CassandraTableScan.scala:29)
at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraTableScan$$anonfun$1.apply(CassandraTableScan.scala:28)
at scala.Function1$$anonfun$andThen$1.apply(Function1.scala:55)
at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraTableScan.inputRdd(CassandraTableScan.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.CassandraTableScan.execute(CassandraTableScan.scala:99)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:84)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.collect(DataFrame.scala:887)
at com.worldline.ms.pcop.crm360.retail.tracking.service.dao.jpa.TrackingDaoImpl.getLastVisitedProduct(TrackingDaoImpl.java:37)
at com.worldline.ms.pcop.crm360.retail.tracking.service.functional.DivolteTrackingFunctionnalServiceImpl.getLastVisitedProduct(DivolteTrackingFunctionnalServiceImpl.java:35)
at com.worldline.ms.pcop.crm360.retail.tracking.service.business.DivolteTrackingBusinessServiceImpl.getLastVisitedProduct(DivolteTrackingBusinessServiceImpl.java:29)
at com.worldline.ms.pcop.crm360.retail.tracking.service.test.DivolteTrackingBusinessServiceTest.testGetLastVisitedProduct(DivolteTrackingBusinessServiceTest.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:81)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:216)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:82)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:60)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:67)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:162)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I know the problem is that my column name is case sensitive ut if i use this query `cassandraContext.sql("SELECT 'userId', timestamp FROM rr")` the result is

```
userIdRDD.collectAsList().get(0) = [userId,1970-01-01 01:00:00.001]
```

How can I get my data from a table column case sensitive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CQL3 treats columns names as case insensitive. Names are always converted to lower case. In order to avoid this you have to double quote the names in Create query. If you executed it in Java, your query should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE zz("timestamp" timestamp, \"sessionId\" text, \"userId\" text, PRIMARY KEY (\"userId\", \"sessionId\", "timestamp"));
```

Note that quotes are escaped. In this case userId and sessionId will not be saved at lower-case.

Hope this helps,

Zoran

Comment: I this is what I did. Not through Java but directly in cqlsh and my table was Ok wih case sensitive. The problem is more in SparkSQL querying the table.

But i finally recreate my table without any majuscule.